# How to count empty lines inside a string in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, newline

I'm trying to count all the empty lines inside a string. My current function kind of works:

```
function count_empty(text) {
    var regex = /\r\n?|\n/g;
    var lines = text.split(regex);
    var sep = [];
    $.each(lines, function(k, val) {
        if(!val) {
            //sentence
            sep.push(val);
        }
    });
    return sep.length;
}
```

...but I really think it could be achieved with a far better approach with something like this:

```
function count_empty(text) {
    return (text.match(/\r\n?|\n/g) || []).length;
}
```

Of course, the regex in the 2nd alternative should be retouched to actually accomplish the requirements. So, the question is: What regex should I use in the second approach to retrieve the blank lines only?

**One consideration**: If a line contains whitespaces only, it will be treated as an empty line.

This textarea's string should return 3 with the function.

```
<textarea id="test">first line

third line


</textarea>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Should this `<textarea id="test"></textarea>` be a count of 1 or 0, i.e. must a line be terminated by `\r?\n`? When you say `spaces` do you mean exactly that or any whitespaces?

Comment: @Xotic750 hi! the count should be 0 in that case, and i meant whitespaces.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you enable multi-line mode, `m`, for your regular expressions, you can match empty lines, `^$`, and count how many matches have been found. Note that `[ \t]*` will match zero or more spaces or tabs.

```
function count_lines(text){
    return text ? (text.match(/^[ \t]*$/gm) || []).length : 0;
}
```

This should be really fast since no post-processing after the regular expression is necessary.

See [Regex101](https://www.regex101.com/r/yX5pS1/1) for a demo with annotations.

Comment: Hi! If I put some extra empty lines at the end of the string, they are not being counted with this regex.

Comment: @andufo, thanks. It looks like the `\s*` quantifier was consuming adjacent newlines. I have updated the regex as necessary.

Comment: Just tried lots of scenarios with your regex, it seems it is working as expected. Thanks!

Comment: Treats `<textarea id="test"></textarea>` as 1 and only handles spaces and tabs and not all whitespaces.

Comment: @Xotic750 you're right, forgot to test that case when the textarea is empty.

Comment: @Xotic750 what do you mean with "not all whitespaces"? I tried lots of spacing scenarios (tabs, empty lines, spaces, and combined) https://www.regex101.com/r/yX5pS1/3

Comment: @Xotic750, thanks. Looks like I missed that case. I just turned it into a ternary to check if the text is an empty string to begin with and return `0` if so.

Comment: @GioBorje No problem, that is why I checked in my comment what the OP actually wanted, an empty string could be considered 1 depending on the case. :)

Comment: Thanks once again to both of you! Looks like a bullet proof and elegant solution.

Comment: @andufo ECMA3 compatible and not a single bit of jQuery in sight. Should really remove that from the question title. ;)

Comment: `[ \t]*` basically count all lines regardless it empty or not. Because of the "*", the line will still match if it has content.

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
function count_empty(text) {
    return (text.match(/(^[ \t]*(\n|$))/gm) || []).length;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gbtzdgy7/1/)

Comment: It isn't counting the last enter (if an empty line is added at the end)

Comment: true, I've updated just in case you want to try some other approaches. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can just do this

```
function count_lines(txt){
   return (txt.match(/\n(?=\n/g)) || []).length;
}
```

What the above does is matches `\n` which is followed by another `\n`, and then returning the length of matches.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/p2ungh7z/)

Comment: Just two things: **1)** i added retouched the return value in case there are no matches (to avoid js errors): `return (text.match(/\n(?=\n)/g) || []).length;` and **2)** for some reason, if I leave one empty line at the end of the string, it is not being counted.

Comment: @andufo it does count. Doesn't it? Try adding an extra line in the demo. It should show 4

Comment: A parenthesis is missing around somewhere after your last update :s

Comment: @andufo yup. A typo :p

Comment: Thanks for the help, had to go with @GioBorje's solution, it worked in all scenarios.

Comment: glad to have helped :)